# Free Language/IDE for Nokia Mobile Development

Tags: nokia

Can you pls advice me to a free and easiest language/IDE for Nokia mobile development ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would probably be Java and either Eclipse or NetBeans

http://www.forum.nokia.com/Technology_Topics/Development_Platforms/Java.xhtml

Comment: Thanks maffel,
What about Oracle JDeveloper ?

Comment: Never used that one so I can't say, but I can't see any reason why that wouldn't do. You might want to look into the plugins and development tools that Nokia provides for the different IDEs before making your mind though.